# Excel Lookup a value from a range of cells

Tags: excel, lookup-tables

I have a table like this
Apple, Orange
Pear, Peache
Banana, Pineapple, Mango

I need to search for Peach in this table and get the cell location.
what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If those are in separate cells, e.g. `A2:A8` you can use a `MATCH` function to get the position within that range, e.g.

`=MATCH("Peach",A2:A8,0)`

If Peach is in cell A5 then that's the 4th cell in the range so the formula will return 4

If Peach exists more than once in the table `MATCH` only finds the first instance

Comment: actually I realized my original table wasnt displayed correctly. The values are not in separate cells unfortunately. Some are combined within the same cell.

Comment: OK so if the commas separate the cells you have 5 cells, right? If you expect Peach to match with "Peache Banana" then you can still use MATCH but with wildcards like this: `=MATCH("*Peach*",A2:A6,0)` - that should give you 3 because it matches with the 3rd cell in the range. Why do you need the location, do you need to use it in another formula?